# When deserializing JSON with C#/NewtonSoft, can you flatten some of the results?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

If my JSON is:

`{ cat: 1, dog: 2, price: { initial: 1, new: 2 } }`

Is it possible to deserialize it into a single class that has the properties cat, dog, initialprice, newprice?

Perhaps there is an attribute or way of using the JsonProperty attribute to do this.

I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: Well, this json is invalid format, so json.net will not recognize

Comment: JSON.net parses this fine for me

Comment: I would look into something like this: http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization if it is something you need to do frequently

Comment: 3 years later, what a about this question with latest versions of newtonsoft.json ?

Answer (score 3):

The following's a bit rough-and-ready but does what I think you're trying to do. Casing is different to your JSON so it won't roundtrip to your input without some modification.

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public decimal Cat { get; set; }
        public decimal Dog { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
        private Price Price { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        public decimal InitialPrice
        {
            get { return this.Price.Initial; }
        }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        public decimal NewPrice
        {
            get { return this.Price.New; }
        }
    }

    class Price
    {
        public decimal Initial { get; set; }
        public decimal New { get; set; }
    }
```

Quick test method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string JSON = "{ cat: 1, dog: 2, price: { initial: 1, new: 2 } }";

        var deserialised = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(JSON);
        var serialised = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialised);
    }
```

We've defined a Price type to match what would naturally be deserialised from the price property in your JSON, made it private and then accessed its members using two read-only properties on the TestClass. So - code will see the structure you want (four properties, Cat, Dog, InitialPrice, NewPrice) parsed from the JSON input you defined.

Comment: That is neat, but the problem was actually that my Json is coming back about 6 levels deep, and I didn't want to create 5 classes with a single property in each one pointing to the next if I could just do `[JsonProperty("price.initial")]` or something to that effect, but no problem :) I think your suggestion will come in useful for me later on!

Comment: Figured it might not be that easy! You can at least probably automate some of the class generation using something like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) but that would still require you to whack accessors in and navigate the property structure that gets generated.